# What is the best source for the IELTS general writing task 1?

Tags: discussion

I'm preparing for the IELTS (General) exam, but I couldn't find a reliable source out there in which the writing task 1 has been presented in depth.
Is there anybody to help me? Thanks in advance.

---

The Writing Task 1 of the IELTS Academic test requires you to write a summary of at least 150 words in response to a particular graph (bar, line or pie graph), table, chart, or process (how something works, how something is done). This task tests your ability to select and report the main features, to describe and compare data, identify significance and trends in factual information, or describe a process. Source: [IELTS-exam.net](https://www.ielts-exam.net/academic_writing_samples_task_1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for those wishing to take either the Academic or the General IELTS exam.

Perhaps one of the best online resources for candidates taking the IELTS exam is **[IELTS Liz](https://ieltsliz.com/ielts-writing-task-1-lessons-and-tips/)**. There are tips, model answers and video tutorials such as this one [IELTS Writing Task 1: How to Describe a Bar Chart](https://youtu.be/E3U1Y1jgGls).

For tips for General writing task 1, see: [IELTS Letter Writing Tips](https://ieltsliz.com/ielts-letter-writing-essential-tips/) and to see a model answer that scored 8 see “[Letter 2017](https://ieltsliz.com/ielts-gt-letter-2017-with-model-answer/)”.

However, for best results, a candidate who needs to earn a 6 or above for IELTS should invest in at least one book. I'd recommend a book with past examination papers published by Cambridge such as *IELTS 12 Academic with answers*  or IELTS 10 (with answers), which covers not only Academic past examination papers but also General Reading and Writing. You can get a copy without the CD if you need to save money but this means you won't be able to practice the listening paper, you'll only have the questions with the script.

Comment: It's really practical, thank you very much