# The IELTS academic exam

Tags: discussion

I want to prepare for the IELTS academic exam, and I am so confused about the best resources. Do you have any suggestion for me?

And in your opinion, which is better **Collins** or **Cambridge** books for IELTS?

Comment: Hello Omar.  Both are fine.  But I've had to vote to close.  Recommendations of books don't work well here as everybody has a different opinion.

Comment: https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15562/44619

Comment: Alright, I just want to know more about other opinions and resources of the exam.

Comment: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5143/what-is-the-best-source-for-the-ielts-general-writing-task-1?rq=1